# FrameLayout after ScrollView allways on bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout

I need to made layout that will contain ScrollView with some dynamic length text and Button in FrameLayout after(below). With long text all is okay, but when text is short button stuck right below bottom of ScrollView text part. I want a FrameLayout in the bottom of the screen when text is short and right below ScrollView text part when text long [image: what i want].
Can it be done?
My XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".TeacherFullActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_teacher_full">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/listview_element_teachers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/job_title"
                    style="@style/TitleMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/teacher_job_title" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/job_dynamic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subject_title"
                    style="@style/TitleMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/teacher_subject_title" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/subject_dynamic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workPlace_title"
                    style="@style/TitleMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/teacher_workplace_title" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/workplace_dynamic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="35dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/teacher_external_link"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
                    android:text="@string/open_link"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>       
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `android:fillViewport` attribute of `ScrollView` to accomplish this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What this does is make it so that, in the case where the contents of the `LinearLayout` are not large enough to fill the screen, the `LinearLayout` is stretched to fill the screen anyway. That gives the `FrameLayout` room to grow (based on its `layout_weight` attribute), which in turn lets the `Button` float to the bottom of the screen (because of its `layout_gravity` attribute).

In cases where the contents of the `LinearLayout` are larger than the screen, no stretching happens. The button is pushed off-screen, but appears when you scroll down (with no space between it and the text).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your approach:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".TeacherFullActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_teacher_full">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/listview_element_teachers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_title"
                style="@style/TitleMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/teacher_job_title" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/job_dynamic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject_title"
                style="@style/TitleMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/teacher_subject_title" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/subject_dynamic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/workPlace_title"
                style="@style/TitleMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/teacher_workplace_title" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/workplace_dynamic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>       
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            app:constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollview"
            app:constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/teacher_external_link"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
                android:text="@string/open_link"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Explaination:**

What i did was took **`FrameLayout`** containing **`Button`** out side of **`ScrollView`** so that it can always be at bottom of the Container.